# Select multiple wp_postmeta keys with single select

Tags: mysql

This is my table.  I simply would like one select statement that returns coupon_code, max_uses, and times_used.  I don't know how to join it all to do that.

```
mysql> select * from wp_postmeta where post_id = '207717';
+---------+---------+------------------------+-------------------------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key               | meta_value                    |
+---------+---------+------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  795679 |  207717 | coupon_code            | emeraldcity                   |
|  795689 |  207717 | max_uses               | 30                            |
|  795699 |  207717 | start_date             | 2016-07-22                    |
|  795704 |  207717 | _end_date              | WPMUDEV_Field_Datepicker      |
|  795705 |  207717 | _edit_lock             | 1492003198:1                  |
|  913311 |  207717 | times_used             | 22                            |
+---------+---------+------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

For example, this gets me just max_uses.

```
mysql> select * from wp_postmeta where post_id = '207717' and meta_key = 'max_uses';
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
|  795689 |  207717 | max_uses | 30         |
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) with just the first parameter ( post ID ) you'll get an array of all the post meta for the passed ID. You'll get more than you expect but you can then use any number of ways to get the data that you want out.

`$post_meta = get_post_meta( 207717 )`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html) Clause

```
mysql> select * from wp_postmeta where post_id = '207717' and meta_key IN ( 'max_uses', 'coupon_code');
+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key    | meta_value  |
+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|  795679 |  207717 | coupon_code | emeraldcity |                   
|  795689 |  207717 | max_uses    | 30          |
+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```